# Using cref in class description with GhostDoc

Tags: ghostdoc

I just started using GhostDoc, so I hope mine is not a stupid question. I want to document Class1 by referring to its method Method1. So, I use cref in the description of Class1 as follows.

```
/// <summary>
/// Use this class to do a lot of things.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// The most interesting method is <see cref="Method1"/>
/// </remarks>
public class Class1
{
    public void Method1(int a)
    { }
}
```

After building the help file with GhostDoc Pro, I noticed that cref did not "bind", that is, in the documentation under Remarks it says:
"The most interesting method is [Method1]" (with no link to Method1). How can I make the link appear?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use fully qualified method name, for example

```
<see cref="M:MyNamespace.Class1.Method1(System.Int32)"/>
```

where MyNamespace is your namespace.

In general it is pretty easy to find correct syntax - turn on XML documentation for project, compile the project, look at the generated XML Comments file for syntax.

For methods that would be

```
M:<namespace>.<class>.<method name>(<parameters>):<return type>
```

We don't mind answering GhostDoc questions on SO but you generally you would be get faster help when ask your questions at our community forums - http://community.submain.com

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, it partially works now: it works only if the parameters are System objects (int, string, etc...) if the signature of Method1 is public void Method1(Class2 a), and I use <see cref="M:MyNamespace.Class1.Method1(MyNamespace.Class2)"/>, then in the documentation it correctly appears as Method1(Class2) but with no link!. How do I show the link?

Comment: Here is how you reference it - <see cref="M:MyNamespace.Class1.Method1(T:MyNamespace.Class2)"/>

Comment: Still doesn't work. The result in the documentation is [M:MyNamespace.Class1.Method1(T:MyNamespace.Class2)] (with of course no link)